# Get item by index from sublist in list

Tags: c#, list

In my actual project, I am actually retrieving data using API with a raw body, and the return results is in JSON. I have tried to give similar example to my code as below...

What I want to achieve is to allow users to do selection in drop down list (Picker in Xamarin Forms), and display the corresponding result afterwards... Meaning, the drop down list will have John and Mark. If user selects John, it will display password: 1234, role: Admin..... I am unsure of how to achieve this because the JSON result is in one whole chunk, similarly to my example of `var exmp`....

My code

```
 var exmp = "User: John, Password: 1234, Role: Admin, User: Mark, Password: 0000, Role: User";
        string[] empTxt = exmp.Split(new[] { ',', ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var user = new List<string>();
        var userdetails = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < empTxt.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (empTxt[i].Equals("User"))
            {

                user.Add(empTxt[i + 1]);
                user.Add(empTxt[i + 3]);
                user.Add(empTxt[i + 5]);
                userdetails.AddRange(user);
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < userdetails.Count(); i++)
        {
            //labelTxt.Text = userdetails.ToString();
              Picker.ItemsSource = userdetails[0]; (can't run code because error)
        }
```

Json body

```
{
        {
            "User": "John",
            "Password": "1234",
            "Role": "Admin",
        },
        {
            "User": "Mark",
            "Password": "0000",
            "Role": "Director",
        }
```

}

Comment: Can you please read [ask]? I can't understand how your code relates to the question. Please give us a [mcve] that gives the error you get.

Comment: ... I want to get the results from `exmp` . I think I mentioned it clearly. What I want to achieve is to get all the User names from string `exmp` which is John and Mark in this example. I want to extract this item out from the list and append them into a dropdownlist by itemsource. This allow users to choose whether they want John or Mark. After choosing from the dropdown list, I would like to show password and role. The error appears when I tried to get specific index to display inside labelTxt

Comment: you have role as "User". So you Equals("User") will not work.

Comment: @Charis - If your question was clear enough I wouldn't ask. Could you please provide a [mcve] that give the error `cannot convert type string to system generic ilist`. The code you have shared does NOT give that error.

Comment: @RajuJoseph hi thank you for the help. i think thats one of the error why the second part doesn't show. I have changed the role to director instead.

Comment: you can get the list of users as follows: 

var foo = exmp.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Where(x => x.Trim().StartsWith("User:"))
                       .Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ':' })[1])
                       .ToList();

now extend the same to get other details. can be done with linq.

Comment: So if you have 10 items, and "User" is in position 9 (index 8), how are you going to access `i + 3` and `i + 5`? Positions 12 (index 11) and 14 (index 13) don't exist...

Comment: @Enigmativity Ok sorry thanks for the tip. The error only shows for Picker. I am using xamarin. It happens at the last for loop when I try to `Picker.ItemsSource = userdetails[0];`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question on the basis that it doesn't fully describe a problem. I've read it several times and it's still not clear what kind of issue you're facing.

Comment: @John The issue is I am not sure how to display the data. In my actual project I have an api with a Json body and I am looping through the Json body to get data. I just want to get all of the User into a list and put them inside a drop down list... then when user do a selection, I want to display the password and role.....

Comment: @Charis - You're being frustrating. Can you please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows the error that you're getting? There is no drop down list in your code. Please show us what we're asking for to help you get a good answer.

Comment: @Charis - If you're working with JSON then use a JSON parser to read the data. How did you get `"User: John, Password: 1234, Role: Admin, User: Mark, Password: 0000, Role: User"` from the JSON?

Comment: @Enigmativity I have updated. The `"User: John, Password: 1234, Role: Admin, User: Mark, Password: 0000, Role: User"` is just an example of the output of my Json. It is simlar. After I do split for Json, i will get every index of the string. What I am doing is to get the next index if it equals to "User" so I can get the next value

Comment: And the problem there is...? What?

Comment: @John I can managed to get all User names (John, Mark etc) inside the picker but if I want to display the password and role for each specific user after the picker selection, I am not sure how to achieve it. That is my problem. Because currently I am just using `i+3, i+5` to retrieve password and role.

Comment: Perhaps you need to create a person _object_ and show that in the list instead.

Comment: @Charis - You really should post questions that solve your real-world problem. I can answer the question, but I'm really hesitant to build an object model from the string given that the string is based on JSON and that's likely to have a better structure in the first place. Can you please post your actual JSON?

Comment: @Enigmativity I can't show you the exact Json values since it is for work but I have updated Json body code. It is the exact format but I changed the values. In actual, I retrieve this body by linking the api, and converted the results into a string. Its okay if you still don't understand thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Given you have the following valid JSON as your input then this all becomes quite trivial.

```
[
  {
    "User":"John","Password":"1234","Role":"Admin"
  },
  {
    "User":"Mark","Password":"0000","Role":"User"
  }
]
```

First define a class that will capture your user data.

```
public class UserRecord
{
    public string User;
    public string Password;
    public string Role;
    public override string ToString() => this.User;
}
```

Now, using `Newtonsoft.Json`, I can deserialize the data like this:

```
UserRecord[] users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserRecord[]>(json);
```

Finally, the binding is super simple.

```
Picker.ItemsSource = users;
```

The override for `ToString()` will determine what data is shown in the drop down. When the user selects an item in the drop down you should just be able to cast the selected item to `UserRecord` to get the rest of the fields.

Let me know if that works.